# List inside a JPQL query

Tags: java, list, jpa, jpql

I have a `Category` class which looks like this:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {

   // other attributes

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "articlecat",
             joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")},
             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "articleId")})
  private List<Article> articleList;

 // other methods
 }
```

How can I query `Categories` using a single `Article`, something like this:

```
SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.articleList contains :article
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MEMBER OF (OF is optional).

```
SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE :article MEMBER OF c.articleList
```

Comment: I've been trying this using IN clause for a while now, not understanding what was wrong... Thanks for your answer, you solved my issue.